Proving $f(n) = 1 + c + c^2 + \cdots + c^n = \Theta(1) $
How can I prove that the function $$ f(n) = 1 + c + c^2 + \cdots + c^n $$ is $\Theta(1)$ when $c<1$?
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, with $c>0$. Can I use limits?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Since $c^0=1$, you can re-write your function in the following way:
$$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n c^n \ .$$
That said, in order to prove that $f(n)=\Theta(1)$, you have to show that $f(n)$ is both $\Omega(1)$ and $O(1)$. This is a direct consequence of the formal definition of $\Theta(\cdot)$ and it is usually the most common way used to prove that a function is $\Theta(\cdot)$ of another function.

The first one is simple because $\Omega$ notation indicates a lower bound and the function is of course $\geq 1$, so we can conclude that $f(n)=\Omega(1)$.
The upper bound is slightly more complicated. In our re-writing of $f$, we have:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c^n \ .$$
This is the famous Geometric Series with parameter $c$, and it is well-known that for $|c|<1$ it converges to $\frac{1}{1-c} $.
We can conclude that $f(n) \leq \frac{1}{1-c}$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and thus we have a constant (it does not depend on $n$) upper-bound for it, thus $f(n)=O(1)$.

Putting everything together, we have $f(n)=\Omega(1)$ and $f(n)=O(1)$, which implies $f(n)=\Theta(1)$.

You do not need the limits here. There is a well known formula for the finite geometric series $\frac{1-c^n}{1-c}$.

@codeR asymptotic notation is about limits. You can either see it in the summation form or in your closed form but you have to take the limit. Of course, if you prove a generic upper bound holding for each $n$ the limit is not necessary, but in general asymptotics are about the limit behaviour
